# Does disabling trigger also disables the index temporarily

Tags: postgresql

I have a standard table

```
 Column |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
--------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer                | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | character varying(255) | 
 email  | character varying(255) | 
 active | boolean                | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Next if I execute

```
ALTER TABLE "users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

then when I execute

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

should the index be used if I check explain ?

As per doc it seems to me that when the triggers are disabled then the primary key index is disabled too.

> DISABLE/ENABLE [ REPLICA | ALWAYS ] TRIGGER These forms configure the
>   firing of trigger(s) belonging to the table. A disabled trigger is
>   still known to the system, but is not executed when its triggering
>   event occurs. For a deferred trigger, the enable status is checked
>   when the event occurs, not when the trigger function is actually
>   executed. One can disable or enable a single trigger specified by
>   name, or all triggers on the table, or only user triggers (this option
>   excludes internally generated constraint triggers such as those that
>   are used to implement foreign key constraints or deferrable uniqueness
>   and exclusion constraints). Disabling or enabling internally generated
>   constraint triggers requires superuser privileges; it should be done
>   with caution since of course the integrity of the constraint cannot be
>   guaranteed if the triggers are not executed. The trigger firing
>   mechanism is also affected by the configuration variable
>   session_replication_role. Simply enabled triggers will fire when the
>   replication role is "origin" (the default) or "local". Triggers
>   configured as ENABLE REPLICA will only fire if the session is in
>   "replica" mode, and triggers configured as ENABLE ALWAYS will fire
>   regardless of the current replication mode.

Comment: Since the doc doesn't mention indexes at all, why do you think it supports your idea that the index should be disabled?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to test it. My guess - disabling triggers wont disable indexes.

Comment: I tested it and found that disabling trigger does not disable indexes and explain still used the index.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling triggers wont disable indexes (Why would it?).

As for plan for

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1;
```

It may or may not use indexes based on many factors. Mainly - the number of records in the table.